# Creating typescript definition (.d.ts) file from multiple files which are using same namespace

Tags: typescript, namespaces, export

I am trying to create typescript definition (.d.ts) file from multiple files which are using same namespace as shown below but the problem occurs bec. of exporting files from index.ts.

Dog.ts

```
export namespace Animal {
 export class Dog {
     
 }
}
```

Fish.ts

```
export namespace Animal {
    export class Fish {
     
    }
}
```

index.ts (which helps to generate index.d.ts automatically when run typescript compiler)

```
export * from "./Dog";
export * from "./Fish";
```

Error: Module "./Dog" has already exported a member named 'Animal'. Consider explicitly re-exporting to resolve the ambiguity.